# XmlHttpRequest doesn't terminate request processing

Tags: php, apache, xmlhttprequest

I've implemented **long polling** mechanism using **XMLHttprequest**. My problem is that after the browser is closed, the server side process continues to run and doesn't shutdown.

The web server is **httpd apache** and the process is a **php** script .

I do want the php script to close after the browser closes .

i discovered that php doesn't discover connection close unless it tries to output data back to the browser .
this is a problem, since it will compromise the objective of minimizing bandwidth usage .

the client side script, uses onreadystatechange to try and read partial data without requiring new XMLHttprequest for each communication .
some browsers will not allow to read partial data until the whole response is finished :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(NewReq);

  var mode = 0;
  function NewReq() {
    var Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'a.php';
    if (mode) {
      url += '?mode=' + mode;
    }
    Req.open('GET', url);
    Req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
      var handler = ReadyState[this.readyState];
      if (typeof handler == 'function') {
        handler(this);
      }
    };
    inc_mycookie();
    Req.send();
  }

  var ReadyState = [
    //'NotInit', 'ReqRec', 'ConEst'
    null , null, null,
    partial // 'Proccessing'
    ,
    complete //'Finishied'
  ];

  function partial(Req) { //'Proc'
    if (mode == 1) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      var strings = Req.response.split(';');
      strings.pop();
      var data = JSON.parse(strings.pop());
      $('#message').text(data);
      mode = 2;
    }
    catch (e) {
      $('#message').text(e.message);
      mode = 1;
    }
    return;
  }

  function complete(Req) {
    var last = $('#message').text();
    $('#output').text(last);
    NewReq();  
  }

  function inc_mycookie() {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(/(?:^|;)mine=([^;]+);?/);
    if (matches) {
      var inc = parseInt(matches[1]) + 1;
      document.cookie = 'mine=' + inc;
    }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3> output </h3>
<div id="output"></div>
<h3> partial </h3>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php script (apache has "php_value output_buffering Off") :

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['mine'])) {
    setcookie('mine', 23);
    $_COOKIE['mine'] = 23;
  }
  $mode = isset($_GET['mode']) ? $_GET['mode'] : 1;
  print json_encode('test_' . $_COOKIE['mine']) . ';';
  if ($mode == 2 ) {
    $iter = 8; 
    while($iter) {
      sleep(2);
      $iter--;
      error_log('a.php:' . $iter);
      // if i remove this line, then erro_log will continue to show even when browser is closed
      print json_encode('test_' . $_COOKIE['mine'] . '_' . $iter) . ';';
    }
  }
?>
```

in the case where browser support partial response, the damage is not too bad .

but if browser require the whole response to finish, then the damage will be a complete compromise of long polling, meaning a repetitive request every 5 seconds .

Comment: What is the code you have so far?

Comment: i added the code, and found that php must try to output data back to client to discover that connection has been aborted

Comment: i completed the final description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to add interval :

```
<?php
$iter = 200; 
while($iter) {
  sleep(2);
  $iter--;
  error_log('a.php:' . $iter);
  if (update_exist()) {
    print json_encode('test_' . $_COOKIE['mine'] . '_' . $iter) . ';';
  }
  else if (($iter-200)%20 == 0) { // 180, 160, 140 ... 40, 20, 0
    print json_encode('check connection : ' . $iter) . ';';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is almost 5 years old, consider

```
XMLHTTPRequest.abort()
```

The javascript in the question would need to be redesigned in the following ways:

1. Make `Req` a global variable, so that
2. `Req.abort()` could be called, in (for instance)
3. `window.addEventListener('unload', function() { Req.abort(); })`

so that closing the page could cause the client to terminate the connection to the server.